# Replace 3-way switch with fan speed controller

Tags: switch, fans

Current situation is a fan/light combination on a three way circuit.  Two switches on opposite sides of the room.
Light is on pull chain.
Replacing the fan.  No light on it.
Variable speed wall switch came with the fan, and we want to keep and use it.  How do I wire it to maintain three way switch control of the fan?

Comment: that can not be done

Comment: What make and model is your new fan?

Answer (score 2):

It is doubtful that the wall switch that was provided with the fan has the capability to provide a 3way connection. ( You can provide the wiring diagram for the fan switch, but the ability to be 3way is still highly unlikely.)

In the event that you do not have an outlet or another hardwired light that is activated with a switch at both entry points to the room, you also now are in code violation. At every entry a switch must be available to activate a light or an outlet that can be used to power a lamp to provide illumination to the room.